# Truth Table Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics, math-expression-eval

In of my software engineering classes, I had to write a truth table calculator in the language of my choice.  This is what I came up with, and I would like to know what I should do better next time:

```
import copy
import sys

print("This program reads boolean equations and outputs the truth table.")
print("You may use the operators ~, ∨, and ∧, or")
print("their text equivalents, not, or, and and.")
print("You may use parenthesis, braces, and brackets to group your equations,")
print("and you must use single letters for your variable names, as 'a∨b'\n")

equation = input()
equation_copy = equation
equation_vars = []
equation = " " + equation + " "
equation = equation.replace("~", " not ")
equation = equation.replace("∨", " or ")
equation = equation.replace("∧", " and ")
equation = equation.replace("[", "(")
equation = equation.replace("]", ")")
equation = equation.replace("{", "(")
equation = equation.replace("}", ")")

for index in range(len(equation)):
    if equation[index] in " ()^":
        continue
    if equation[index + 1] in " ()" and equation[index - 1] in " ()" and equation[index] not in equation_vars:
        equation_vars.append(equation[index])

equation_vars.sort()

for equationIndex in equation_vars:
    sys.stdout.write(equationIndex + '\t')

print(equation_copy)

for equationIndex in range(pow(2,len(equation_vars))):
    vals = str(bin(equationIndex)).replace('0b','').zfill(len(equation_vars))

    for value in vals:
        sys.stdout.write(value + '\t')

    equation_vars_copy = copy.deepcopy(equation_vars)
    for index in range(len(equation_vars_copy)):
        equation_vars_copy[index] += " = " + vals[index]
        exec(equation_vars_copy[index])

    truthTable = "result = equation"
    truthTable = truthTable.replace('equation', equation)
    exec(truthTable)
    if result:print(1)
    else:print(0)
```

I have a working version at [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/Gd1K3s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's proceed top-down.  I'll suggest cleverer ways to do a bunch of stuff, but the review will culminate in the two most important points:

- this is a huge security hole, and
- you should organize your code into functions.

### Introductory message

A good way to write a multiline string is using [`"""the longstring"""` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

In this case, though, that introductory message could just as well be the docstring for the program.  You could use the special `__doc__` variable to fetch the docstring by introspection.

```
"""This program reads boolean expressions and outputs the truth table.
You may use the operators ~, ∨, and ∧, or
their text equivalents, not, or, and and.
You may use parenthesis, braces, and brackets to group your expressions,
and you must use single letters for your variable names, as 'a∨b'"""

print(__doc__)
```

Note that "equation" is not the right word: you don't want a string with an equals sign.  You just want a "boolean expression".

### Canonicalizing the expression

Doing string substitutions in multiple passes is bad practice.  In the best case, you waste a bit of effort making multiple passes over the string.  In the worst case, passing previously substituted text through another round could be incorrect — though fortunately that's not the case here.

I recommend doing the substitution in one pass using a regular expression.

```
REPLACEMENTS = {
   '~': ' not ',
   'v': ' or ',
   '^': ' and ',
   '[': '(',
   ']': ')',
   '{': '(',
   '}': ')',
}
expr = re.sub('|'.join(re.escape(sym) for sym in REPLACEMENTS.keys()),
              lambda sym: REPLACEMENTS[sym.group(0)],
              expr).strip()
```

### Extracting the variables

This, too, can be simplified using a regular expression.  `\b[A-Za-z]\b` looks for any single letter bounded by word boundaries on both sides.

In addition, deduplication is more elegant using a `set`.

```
vars = sorted(set(re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]\b', expr)))
```

### Generating the boolean values

This is a perfect job for [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and in fact the documentation has just such an example:

```
product(range(2), repeat=len(vars))
```

### Evaluating the expression

First of all, you should use [`eval()`, not `exec()`](//stackoverflow.com/q/2220699/1157100), since you want to evaluate the expression and get its value, rather than running some code for its side-effect.  `result = eval(expr)` is better than `exec('result = ' + expr)`.

Most importantly, though, **calling `eval()` or `exec()` like that is a huge security hole** — it lets the user execute arbitrary Python code.  For example, the user might enter this to be executed:

```
__import__('os').system('rm -rfi /')
```

The consensus is that [Python can't be safely sandboxed](//stackoverflow.com/q/2220699/1157100).  We can try to do better by evaluating the expression in a scope that contains just the relevant variables.

```
NO_GLOBALS = {'__builtins__': {}}
for vals in product(range(2), repeat=len(vars)):
    locals = dict(zip(vars, vals))
    result = eval(expr, NO_GLOBALS, locals)
```

However, I suspect that even that won't be secure.  The `lambda` keyword is still available, for example, and that makes me nervous.  Ultimately, the only safe approach may be to write your own code to parse and evaluate the expression — Python itself is too powerful.

### Suggested solution

As a final remark: **the problem can be divided neatly into functions**.  Naming these chunks of work make your code easier to follow.

```
"""This program reads boolean expressions and outputs the truth table.
You may use the operators ~, ∨, and ∧, or
their text equivalents, not, or, and and.
You may use parenthesis, braces, and brackets to group your expressions,
and you must use single letters for your variable names, as 'a∨b'"""

from itertools import product
import re

def canonicalize(expr):
    REPLACEMENTS = {
       '~': ' not ',
       'v': ' or ',
       '^': ' and ',
       '[': '(',
       ']': ')',
       '{': '(',
       '}': ')',
    }
    return re.sub('|'.join(re.escape(sym) for sym in REPLACEMENTS.keys()),
                  lambda sym: REPLACEMENTS[sym.group(0)],
                  expr).strip()

def extract_variables(expr):
    return sorted(set(re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]\b', expr)))

def truth_table(expr):
    expr = canonicalize(expr)
    vars = extract_variables(expr)
    NO_GLOBALS = {'__builtins__': {}}

    # Print header
    print('\t'.join(vars + [expr]))

    # Print body
    for vals in product(range(2), repeat=len(vars)):
        locals = dict(zip(vars, vals))
        result = eval(expr, NO_GLOBALS, locals)
        print('\t'.join([str(v) for v in vals] + [str(result)]))

def prompt_expr():
    print(__doc__)
    print()
    return input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    truth_table(prompt_expr())
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to split that `re.sub` into multiple logical lines (`regex = re.compile('|'.join(...)); return regex.sub(...).strip()`). Alternatively with the upcoming `regex` library you can do `regex.sub(r"\L<chars>", ..., chars=REPLACEMENTS)`.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about how to approach the `eval` problem safely, and it occurred to me that the best way to avoid building a parser would be too hook into Python's `ast` module. There is a convenient `NodeVisitor` class that can let us do recursive evaluation of a tree. This is somewhat fiddly so I'll just give you what I came up with.

```
import ast
import operator

class BoolExprEvaluator(ast.NodeVisitor):
    ops = {
        ast.And: operator.and_,
        ast.Or: operator.or_,
        ast.Not: operator.not_
    }

    def __init__(self, vars):
        self.vars = vars

    def callop(self, op, *args):
        return self.ops[type(op)](*args)

    def generic_visit(self, tree):
        """
        Overload the fallback visitor to throw an error.
        This should not be called from user code.
        """

        msg = "Can't evaluate expression containing {} ast nodes"
        raise ValueError(msg.format(type(tree).__name__))


    def visit_Module(self, module):
        [expr] = module.body
        return self.visit(expr)

    def visit_Expr(self, expr):
        return self.visit(expr.value)


    def visit_BoolOp(self, boolop):
        left, right = map(self.visit, boolop.values)
        return self.callop(boolop.op, left, right)

    def visit_UnaryOp(self, unaryop):
        expr = self.visit(unaryop.operand)
        return self.callop(unaryop.op, expr)


    def visit_Name(self, name):
        return self.vars[name.id]
```

Used like:

```
tree = ast.parse("(a or not b and b) or (a or b)")
BoolExprEvaluator({"a": False, "b": False}).visit(tree)
#>>> False
```

This hooks into 200_success' version quite neatly.

Also note that currently you support

```
a && b
a // (a or not a)
```

By using a well-defined API you can avoid such strange results and give better errors messages. Even better would be building a parser yourself, but that sounds a touch harder.

I would also consider doing substitutions and finding all name tokens at the token level simply because it allows supporting things like

```
abc∨def
```

which currently throws an unhappy error. You could also do whitelisting at the same time, further reducing the amount of unwanted computation that can happen. This is a bit long because each case needs dealing with separately but the cases themselves are rather straightforward:

```
import io
import tokenize

def transform_token(token):
    if token.type in (tokenize.ENCODING, tokenize.NAME, tokenize.ENDMARKER):
        return token

    elif token.type == tokenize.OP:
        if token.string in {"~", "(", ")"}:
            return token

        elif token.string in {"{", "["}:
            return token._replace(string="(")

        elif token.string in {"}", "]"}:
            return token._replace(string=")")

        else:
            err = "Only '~', '∨', '∧' and bracketing operators allowed; got {!r}"
            raise ValueError(err.format(token.string))

    elif token.type == tokenize.ERRORTOKEN and token.string == "∨":
        return token._replace(type=tokenize.OP, string=" or ")

    elif token.type == tokenize.ERRORTOKEN and token.string == "∧":
        return token._replace(type=tokenize.OP, string=" and ")

    raise ValueError("Invalid token: {!r}".format(token))

def token_filter(tokens, names):
    for token in tokens:
        if token.type == tokenize.NAME:
            names.add(token.string)

        yield transform_token(token)
```

Usage requires tokenization:

```
equation = "[abc]∨∧~(def)"
stream = io.BytesIO(equation.encode("utf8")).read
tokens = tokenize.tokenize(stream)
```

and then you pass it through before detokenizing:

```
names = set()
transformed = token_filter(tokens, names)
tokenize.untokenize(transformed).decode("utf8")
names
```

The result of both of these is that you force a rather strong well-formedness requirement on input and it's basically impossible for input to do something bad. Errors are also better and identifiers can be of any length.

The one thing I can think of that isn't covered by this is that it still allows improperly matched brackets:

```
[ a )
```

If bracketing substitution was done at the AST level, this would be dealt with by `ast.parse` but it would rather hacky. A better option might be keeping a bracket stack during `transform_token`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a draft for an improved version of your code. I'll comment on things I have changed as soon as I have time. Also, many things are still to be done like getting rid of `exec`.

Well, actually, [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/75781/9452) said it all.

```
import copy
import itertools
import sys

def get_equation_from_user():
    print("This program reads boolean equations and outputs the truth table.")
    print("You may use the operators ~, ∨, and ∧, or")
    print("their text equivalents, not, or, and and.")
    print("You may use parenthesis, braces, and brackets to group your equations,")
    print("and you must use single letters for your variable names, as 'a∨b'\n")
    # commented for testing purposes: return input()
    return "(a ∧ b) ∨ c"

def convert_equation_to_python(equation):
    new_eq = equation
    new_eq = new_eq.replace("~", " not ")
    new_eq = new_eq.replace("∨", " or ")
    new_eq = new_eq.replace("∧", " and ")
    new_eq = new_eq.replace("[", "(")
    new_eq = new_eq.replace("]", ")")
    new_eq = new_eq.replace("{", "(")
    new_eq = new_eq.replace("}", ")")
    new_eq = " " + new_eq + " "
    return new_eq

def get_sorted_variables(python_equation):
    variables = set()
    for index in range(len(python_equation)):
        c = python_equation[index]
        if c not in " ()^" and python_equation[index + 1] in " ()" and python_equation[index - 1] in " ()":
            variables.add(c)
    return sorted(variables)


equation = get_equation_from_user()
pyt_equation = convert_equation_to_python(equation)
equation_vars = get_sorted_variables(pyt_equation)

print('\t'.join(equation_vars) + '\t' + equation)

for vals in itertools.product(['0', '1'], repeat=len(equation_vars)):
    for eq, val in zip(equation_vars, vals):
        exec(eq + " = " + val)
    exec("result = " + pyt_equation)
    print('\t'.join(vals) + '\t' + str(1 if result else 0))
```